# Derivatives of Minkowski function?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ and $M$ be the convex hull of the set $A$, e.g., $M:=Conv(A)$. The Minkowski function on $M$ is defined as follows
\begin{align*}
&f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R\\
&f(x):=\inf\{t\ge 0: x\in tM\}.
\end{align*}
I was wondering if this function has a gradient respect to $x$ or not?

Comment: If $M$ is the unit ball, then $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert$. So the short answer is no.

Comment: $|x|$ has a gradient everywhere but $0$. More generally, $f$ is convex and therefore differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: Here you can suppose that $A$ as an union of the ball.

Comment: Just an idea. Usually (I don't know the precise assumptions), the functional $f$ is a norm having $M$ as unit ball. Differentiability of $f$ is therefore related to the smoothness of the boundary of $M$. (I learned about this relationship [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/227372/8157), look for "Gâteaux derivative"). Also, since $f$ is homogeneous of degree $1$, it is never going to be differentiable at the origin.

Comment: If $A$ is the union of a finite number of balls, then the boundary is $C^1$. In fact, I believe that it is $C^{1,1}$ and in fact smooth except on a lower dimensional set.